# Why do I obtain the same tag with all the test words when using hmms on nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I am currently using Nltk 3.0 with Python 3. I am training the HMMs tagger of nltk with 80% of my corpus (1500 sentences) and testing with the other 20%. I obtain approximately an accuracy of 50% but I try to tag a sentence all the words are tagged with the same tag ('NOUN'). Can you please help me with this issue.

Comment: Could you upload your corpus somewhere online so that we can help to debug the problem? Otherwise any answer would be sort of long shot in the  dark.

Comment: please post some code as well